# Service Worker caching eventsource, xhr

Tags: service-worker, cacheapi

I have a service worker running and registered - it adds a bunch of files to the "static cache" - as files are initiated / requested - they are dynamically added to the cache - it's running and working fine - however, I notice that the live data in the html is not being updated - I used Dev tools to investigate further and noticed that eventsource and xhr were being cached by the service worker - however fetch requests aren't. has anyone else come across this / found a solution?

```js
var CACHE_STATIC_NAME = 'static-v1';
var CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME = 'dynamic-v1';

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Installing Service Worker ...', event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_STATIC_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('[Service Worker] Precaching App Shell');
        cache.addAll([  

'index.html',
'CSS/style.css',
'CSS/style-responsive.css',
'CSS/default-theme.css',
'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff',
'IMAGES/company.png',
'IMAGES/icon.png',
'IMAGES/bg.png',
'IMAGES/header.png',
'CSS/Icons/Android/48.png',
'app.js' ]);
      })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Activating Service Worker ....', event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys()
      .then(function(keyList) {
        return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
          if (key !== CACHE_STATIC_NAME && key !== CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME) {
            console.log('[Service Worker] Removing old cache.', key);
            return caches.delete(key);
          }
        }));
      })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response) {
          return response;
        } else {
          return fetch(event.request)
            .then(function(res) {
              return caches.open(CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME)
                .then(function(cache) {
                  cache.put(event.request.url, res.clone());
                  return res;
                })
            })
            .catch(function(err) {

            });
        }
      })
  );
});
```

[image]

Comment: From what I can see, dashboard.html makes an eventsource request for status.php, it's not in the cache so the service worker makes a fetch. I don't see the problem.

Comment: the issue is it is returning old data - it reads status.php - caches the data and it doesnt get updated - it requests the page but doesn't return new data - hope that makes sense - if i go navigate to status.php in a different browser window the data gets updated